# backbone.js controller not working

Tags: javascript, controller, backbone.js

What am I doing wrong?

**html:**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="js/libs/json2.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

**script.js file:**

```
Controller = Backbone.Controller.extend({
   routes: {
      ':name': 'respond'
   },
   respond : function(name) {
      console.log('it works!');
   }
});
var controller = Controller;
```

Now when I enter http://localhost/backbonetest/#somethink nothink happens.

Comment: Was something supposed to happen? BTW showing us an URL to the file on your local webserver isn't particularly useful; we can't access that.

Comment: I've based my code on this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519619/backbone-js-multiple-level-navigation-example. I expect my code to show a 'it works' message when I type the url.

Comment: I don't see any code here that would do that. You define a function to do it, but there's nothing to ever invoke it. Maybe you're after an `initialize` function.

Comment: according to this http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Controller-routes I thought that the script would execute the function which is bind to the 'route:help' when I enter site#help.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `var controller = new Controller()` ? As it is, it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I You want Your route bind's work, use this code after initializing your controllers:

```
Backbone.history.start()
```

resource: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History-start

Now if you type:

```
http://example.com/#something
```

You will see 'it works' in Your console.

Answer (score 0):

Please use your browsers JavaScript console to see the error log. I find chrome to be better at JavaScript debugging because it's less forgiving to JavaScript errors than other browsers